# Use TemplateContext instead of TemplateContext?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I just upgraded my project from ServiceStack 5.1 to 5.5.1. Now where I am using TemplateContext from ServiceStack.Templates it tells instead to use TemplateContext. Needless to say, this is likely a mistake in the description for the Obsolete attribute. What is the appropiate replacement for TemplateContext now in ServiceStack 5.5.1?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The depreciation message should’ve said to use `ScriptContext` instead.

In the latest ServiceStack v5.5 Release [ServiceStack Templates has been rebranded to #Script.](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#script-fka-servicestack-templates)

The section on [Migration to new Script API's](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.5#migration-to-new-script-apis) explains how to migrate in more detail:

Migrating to the new APIs is fairly straight forward:

- Change `using ServiceStack.Templates;` to `using ServiceStack.Script;`
- Any classes with `TemplatePage*` has been renamed to `SharpPage*`
- Any other class with a `Template*` prefix has been renamed to `Script*`

This change doesn’t affect any of your existing #Script source code whose existing syntax and available filters/methods remains unchanged.

#### New Terminology

The primary rationale for the rebranding was so we’re better able to label, describe and document all of `#Script` different features easier, so when referring to Templates **View Engine** we’re now calling **Sharp Pages** which is a better corollary to “Razor Pages” which it provides an alternative to.

Other re-branded features:

- [API Pages](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/api-pages) are now called [Sharp APIs](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apis)
- [Web Apps](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/web-apps) are now called [Sharp Apps](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps)
- [Template Filters](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/filters) are now called [Script Methods](https://sharpscript.net/docs/methods)
- [Template Blocks](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/blocks) are now called [Script Blocks](https://sharpscript.net/docs/methods)

The collection of methods you inject in your scripts like `TemplateRedisFilters` and `TemplateDbFilters` are now referred to as “Scripts” where they’ve been renamed to `RedisScripts` and `DbScripts`.